# Error in setting up Laravel sail with docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker

Working on setup for a php class, and I keep running into an error when trying to setup the example windows laravel app from the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation#getting-started-on-windows). After entering:

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

I get the following error:

```
Processing fstab with mount -a failed.

<3>WSL (17) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:358: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (17) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:362: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (17) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:570: execvpe /bin/bash failed 2
<3>WSL (17) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:579: Create process not expected to return
```

As far as I know, I have docker and wsl2 installed correctly so I am unsure as to what is causing this error. I have Ubuntu installed as well, but unless I misunderstood the docs, I should just be able to punch the curl straight into cmd prompt to build it in the desired directory.

Comment: This very suspiciously looks like a problem with you wsl installation rather than with the exact task your trying to pursue. What happens if you simply launch a bash prompt inside wsl?

Comment: I ran wsl -l -v to check if I had installed it, which returns 

  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* docker-desktop-data    Running         2
  Ubuntu-22.04           Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2

 but being that I am new to this, I don't really know if that is a good indication of a successful installation, I can try running through the process again when I have time.